# How do I use the substr function to grab the last 100 bytes of a 32K in length string?

Tags: java, string, substring

Summary question: how do I correctly use the substr function to grab the last 100 bytes of a 32K in length string in Java?

I have to admit my C/C++ is slim and little used and my Java experience is well these couple of programs I am currently fighting with.

Just trying to get a test of passing a string back and forth to the mainframe which is my comfortzone (no comments please... ;-)...not in a wheelchair for at least another 3 decades....really!)

The string is just under 32K and back on the PC Eclipse IDE side I have it defined as:

```
String Hold_Container_Data = cont.getCHARData();
```

The sample I copied defaulted to printing everything with a System.out.println the 10 strings of 32K are overwhelming the IDE console.  So trying to fix that.

So I simply wanted to display the first 100 and last 100 bytes since the diagnostic display is handy to have working.

Got the first 100 bytes easily with:

```
Hold_Container_Data.substring( 0, 100 );
```

Started with:

```
Hold_Container_Data.substring( length-100, 100 );
```

which I figured might be syntax issue even though it compiled fine.

For grins I tried both:

```
Hold_Container_Data.substring( 31000, 100 );
Hold_Container_Data.substring( 500, 100 );
```

The latter receives a:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -400
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
```

Again for my grins I tried:

```
Hold_Container_Data.substring( 10, 100 );
```

which sort of worked?

and:

```
Hold_Container_Data.substring( 100, 100 );
```

Which seemed to print blanks??  when those positions should not be white space.

When I use the following:

```
int mylength = Hold_Container_Data.length();
```

and then print with:

```
System.out.println
```

the value is correct to what the actual string length is?

I use the debugger and look at the arg0 and arg1 to the substring function as well as the string data area itself and they all look fine to my limited use of Java?

So there must be something extremely simple I am missing here?

Could someone please enlighten me to an area I can look?

Thanks in advance for you patience with me on a new developer platform!

Comment: You don't need to include Java in the title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: As a side note, 100 characters of a String is actually *200* bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at the JavaDocs is always a good thing, many questions are answered there. For example SubString has a [second function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) to copy the last chars starting from x.

```
Hold_Container_Data.substring(Hold_Container_Data.length() - 100);
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Reading [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) helps:

> public String substring(int beginIndex,
>                  int endIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

Given this description, calling

```
Hold_Container_Data.substring( length-100, 100 );
```

makes no sense.

You should also read about naming conventions, and respect the Java ones when coding in Java. Also note that Strings don't contain bytes, but characters.

Answer (score 1):

Summary answer:

```
int length = Hold_Container_Data.length();
String str = Hold_Container_Data.substring(length-100,length);
```

Comment: This is actually what I did the first time, I forgot to include the int statement, but it was there.  However, it looks right, but it gave me the out of bounds.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the fine manual? From the Javadoc:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)

Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. 
The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and 
extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the 
length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

Examples:

     "hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"
     "smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"


Parameters:
    beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
    endIndex - the ending index, exclusive. 
Returns:
    the specified substring. 
Throws:
    IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, 
    or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object,
    or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.
```